# Selenium accept cookies python

Tags: python, selenium, web

I am trying to accept cookies on website, sadly I cannot refer to the "accept all" button.
I have directly in the code time.sleep(10) so there should not be a problem with the wait on the popup/consent to be visible - which is something I mostly saw in similar threads.

```
driver.get("https://fischer.cz")
time.sleep(10)        
prijmoutVse = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sc-gtsrHT ctrzIr']")
driver.click(prijmoutVse)
```

I am getting selenium error that says it is unable to locate the element.
I am unable to locate it with xpath helper in browser even when I copy the full xpath, all the results are null.

I tried driver.switch_to.alert as well but did not get this to working.

Tried following locators :

```
//*[@data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]
/html/body/div[15]//section/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/button[3]
//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/button[3]
```

[code of the consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zeaD.png)
here is print of the element from console, I noticed there are some "flex" tags but not too sure what they mean or if it could cause trouble.

I am kinda desperate at this point since it blocks my work and I cant figure a way to work around it. I will be happy for any comments or thoughts how to solve that!

Thanks in advance

E1: tried the answer from cruisepandey
getting this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KDK/Desktop/NOVY SEARCH AUTO/test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

E2: tried answer from pmadhu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KDK/Desktop/NOVY SEARCH AUTO/test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    shadowroot.find_element_by_css_selector("#uc-center-container > div > div.sc-hiKfDv.gGhxCY > div > div.sc-ezzafa.bUHURR > div > button.sc-gtsrHT.ctrzIr").click()
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 430, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 658, in find_element
    return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#uc-center-container > div > div.sc-hiKfDv.gGhxCY > div > div.sc-ezzafa.bUHURR > div > button.sc-gtsrHT.ctrzIr"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the website is launched, I see `Přijmout vše` button, I think you wanna click on that.

try with below **code** :-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://fischer.cz/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

outer = expand_shadow_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#usercentrics-root"))
inner = outer.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")
inner.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

The element is in a `Shadow root`

Try below code.

```
driver.get("https://www.fischer.cz/")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_id("usercentrics-root")
shadowroot = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", root1)
shadowroot.find_element_by_css_selector("#uc-center-container > div > div.sc-hiKfDv.gGhxCY > div > div.sc-ezzafa.bUHURR > div > button.sc-gtsrHT.ctrzIr").click()
```