# how to accept a forced cookie with selenium webbrowser

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get to accept a cookie and looked at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649189/selenium-accept-cookies-python).
This is how the popup looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxChW.png
I have tried different things. For instance I tried following the others question solution like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.volkskrant.nl/best-gelezen?utm_source=pocket_mylist')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 4)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.message-component:nth-child(1)')))
```

This however gives the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMu6S.png) error.
I tried a bunch of different things but I can't seem to select anything on the page (at least nothing from the popup).
I know this question has already been asked a couple of times but I did not find a solution.
Is there anyone else who encountered this problem and knows how to just accept the cookies as to go to the regular site?
thanks in advance!

Comment: I see indeed you're right!

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an iframe :

```
iframe[title='Iframe title']
```

you need to switch first in Selenium.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='Iframe title']")))
```

after this you can click on accept cookies button.

**full code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.volkskrant.nl/best-gelezen?utm_source=pocket_mylist")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='Iframe title']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Akkoord']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This element is inside an iframe.
So you have first switch to that iframe and only after that you will be able to accept the cookies.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.volkskrant.nl/best-gelezen?utm_source=pocket_mylist')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'preload')]")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[title="Akkoord"]'))).click()
```